# Error when post data with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

When I using ajax post data with struct

[image: firebug]

And I get data from code here:

`$_POST["post"];` => result is 979, that's OK

`$_POST["href[href]"];` => result is 0, How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bracket notation is used to create an array entry. Use this instead:

```
$_POST["href"]["href"];
```

---

Calling `$_POST["href"]` will return an associative array:

```
array(
    'commentID' => 297980913637729,
    'href' => 'http://dongcam.vn/t3927'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a multidimensional array, so:

```
$_POST["href"]["href"];
```